# Wildfly crashes when SpringBoot load test is near the end

Tags: performance, spring-boot, resources, wildfly, centos6

I have this scenario: a 4GB RAM centos machine, running two tomcats, one with 3 apps in it, another one running 2 apps, and one wildfly with one app runnning on it.

Also, I have a SpringBoot app (tomcat embedded) exposing a rest api, listening on some port.

Wildfly is running with xmx of 3072 and xms 2048.
Tomcats are running with xmx of 1024 and xms 512 each.

I'm load testing the springBoot app and when is almost done, wildfly process crashes.

I see the memory usage is, as expected, almost maximum and CPU also, specially on the springBoot process.

My question is, is this a linux-centos condition that prioritizes some process over another and kill it? Or a JVM condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Linux is running low on memeory the out of memory killer will select one or more processes to kill. One of the selection criteria is the amount of memory the process is using. The higher the memory usage the higher the badness rating. This makes it likely that your Wildfly process will be killed. You can read more about the OOM killer and the selection criteria [here](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. This is very helpful.